# User specified 2d array element values

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, element

```
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                while (treasures >= 0) {
                    mapArray[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(2);
                    treasures -= 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

The user specifies the array's height and width, along with how many "treasures" this array contains. The code should cycle through all of the array's elements, giving them a value of either 0 or 1 ( until the number of treasures entered by the user reaches 0 ).

Treasure indication is 1.

Right now the for loops only target the first ( [0] [0] ) element.

Comment: 0 and 1 should be assigned randomly to the array elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should eliminate the while loop, since it prevents `i` and `j` from being incremented until it ends, which is why only `mapArray[0][0]` is assigned.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < height && treasures >= 0; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width && treasures >= 0; j++) {
            mapArray[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(2);
            treasures -= 1;            
        }
    }
```

Note that if `treasures < height * width`, some elements of the array will contain 0 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the while loop, as it forces to only run for mapArray[0][0] and while loop ends when treasures become zero. This eventually terminates all the loops.

Answer (score 0):

I think number of "treasures" is associated with "1". So if the user wants the array's height to be 4 and width also 4 and "treasures" to be for example 3 i would expect something like this: three "1" and rest "0"

```
     0110
     1000
     0000
     0000
```

in that case you may try

```
Random rnd = new Random();
    int [][] grid = new int[height][width];
    int treasures = 3;

        for (int[] row : grid){                
            for (int n : row){                    
                if(treasures>0){
                    n = rnd.nextInt(2);
                    if(n==1){
                       treasures -= 1;
                    }
                }
                System.out.print(n);
            }
          System.out.println();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand your code, I encourage you to take a pen and write what your code do.

For example :

- Input height=2, width=3, treasures=1
- Step 1 **i=0 and height>i** => **2>1** => continue (height=2, width=3, treasures=1, i=0)
- Step 2 **j=0 and width>j** => **3>0** => continue (height=2, width=3, treasures=1, i=0, j=0)
- Step 3 **treasure >= 0** => **1>=0** => continue
- Step 4 **mapArray[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(2);** => **mapArray[0][0] = rnd.nextInt(2);**
- Step 5 **treasures -= 1** => **treasure = 0** (height=2, width=3, treasures=0, i=0, j=0)
- Step 6 **treasure >= 0** => **0>=0** => continue [I think you don't want this but it's not the problem that causes your question]
- Step 7 **mapArray[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(2);** => **mapArray[0][0] = rnd.nextInt(2);** ...

**Now a few hints to continue :**

> The code should cycle through all of the array's elements, giving them a value of either 0 or 1 ( until the number of treasures entered by the user reaches 0 ).

You can translate it into : I need to place my X treasures into my map.

So the while loop is a good idea, but it's actually in a wrong place. Delete the 2 for loops and keep only the while loop to begin with.

Now think and find a way to put these treasures, one by one, in the right place on your map.

Later, if you need to run through you map, then you will need your 2 for loops. It can be usefull to display your map for example.

Don't forget to check that your inputs are valid.